# Align DIVs next to each other on Internet Explorer 5

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to align two divs next to each other. I achieved it by using the following code:

[Fiddle.js](https://jsfiddle.net/ztkoggbv/)

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
display: table;
width: 100%;
border:5px solid blue;
}

.left {
display: inline-block;
width:10%;
height:160px;
display: table-cell;
border:5px solid red;
}

.right {
vertical-align:top;
display: inline-block;
height:160px;
display: table-cell;
border:5px solid grey;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">DIV #1</div>
    <div class="right">DIV #2</div>
</div>
```

This works for all Browser except for our IE which is run in IE5-Mode since we use some Web-Dynpros which unfortunately need this engine to render properly. However the Internet Explorer does not display the divs as I want them to. In IE it looks like in the following picture:

[Image](http://s22.postimg.org/836plg8tt/Ist.jpg)

Comment: I can't check because i don't have IE5. Check it's working in IE 5 https://jsfiddle.net/ztkoggbv/1/

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't change the outcome. You can set every IE into IE5 by using the Developer Tools (F12)

Comment: Why are you supporting IE5?

Comment: because we need to run Web-Dynpro based applications in the browser. And SAP only supports IE5 with their framework.

Comment: You must be using a really old version as SAP do [support modern browsers](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/WDABAP/Browser+supporting). Has it not been updated in 15 years?

Comment: We are running NetWeaver 7.3 EHP1 SP15, so its actually one of the newer versions. In the link you posted please see this line: For Internet Explorer document modes (Standards, QUIRKS) please see this page for more information: http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/WDABAP/Internet+Explorer+document+modes

Comment: check css property support browser -  http://caniuse.com/#search=inline

Comment: Try setting a propper width for `.right`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border:5px solid blue;
    height:300px;
}
.box
{
   border:5px solid green;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  width: 80%;
  height:250px;
}
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20%;
    height:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    border:5px solid red;
    float:left;
}
.right {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    border:5px solid grey;
    float:right;
    margin-top:110px;
   position:absolute;
   margin-left:100px;
   width:300px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/ztkoggbv/2/)